# How to fetch existing EC2 instance id and store it to an array using AWS CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

I want to create CloudWatch CPU utilization monitoring of EC2 instances using CDK and I want to create an alarm for each instance which will trigger SNS notification if the threshold is exceeded.

Instead of hard coding those instance ids, I would like to fetch them directly from AWS and save them into an array. The problem is that I didn't find any method which would allow me to list all EC2 instances. Ideally I would like to use method similar to vpc.fromLookup but for EC2, does this even exist?

Comment: Are you using AWS CDK for Python ?

Comment: I am using TypeScript but Python should not be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options, but it depends on your exact use case.

If you're talking about instances that you're creating in the same stack, the AWS CDK ec2 `Instance` type, [has a property `instanceId`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.Instance.html#instanceid). This instance id will be added in the template as a reference to the correlated `Instance` resource and CloudFormation will resolve this when deploying.

If you're talking about creating a different stack and just wanting to fetch the currently running instances, you have to use the AWS SDK. You can use [the `ec2.describeInstances` method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#describeInstances-property) to find all instances and get the instance IDs that way.

Comment: EC2 instances are already created manually or using CloudFormation templates. In the CFN case I have exported instanceId as an export parameter but it wouldn't solve my issue because the exported value would still be hard coded only in different format.

The SDK way sounds good to me. What is the best practice, is it alright to mix CDK and SDK in one stack?

Comment: Yes, that's no problem. That's one of the benefits of using the CDK vs classic CloudFormation.

Comment: Please do you have any example of the CDK and SDK code in one stack? How does the deployment work?

Comment: I do not have examples that I'm free to share, but how would that impact deployment? The purpose of CDK is that you can combine it with any other code that is necessary to create the constructs regardless of what that other code is. You can look at it this way, you have one function that retrieves the necessary data from the AWS platform using the AWS SDK and the return values of that you can provide as a parameter to your CDK stack.